Issue with creating icons in Tkinter columns
I am having an issue with my code where I would like to put icons in the second column of a tkinter treeview but so far I have only been able to to get the icons to work in the first column. I can't get it to work in other columns. This is exhibited by the following image:
Bad image
The icons show up in the first column. I would like them to show up in the Get/Checked column.  The state of the buttons work when I click in the Get/Check column, that is, the button presses down and then up. Also the check box checks and unchecks. I would just like to see them work in the second column.
I am using Python 3.10.1 and the latest version of Tkinter
Tkinter version: 8.6
Tcl version: 8.6
Tk version: 8.6.12
Here is the code:
Example to follow
There are other files such as CSV files and Project files but you just need to look at the TreeView in the Frame called Flight Path Methods to see what my problem is.  In fact after this I would like to have other columns with up/down arrows next to these items to allow the user to move the items below the flight data parameters up and down in the list so their order of operation can be changed.
Thanks

Please [edit] your question to include relevant code in the body of the question. We can't easily work with images of code.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

The treeview only accepts images in that one column. There is no way to put images in other columns.
